# Delphi Chromium Embedded (TChromium) - How to mute all sounds?

Tags: delphi, chromium-embedded, tchromium

Is there a way to prevent sounds to play when loading webpages in TChromium? In fact I want no sound to be played by my app.

Comment: I don't think there is a simple way to prevent sounds being played from webpage without muting your entire application. This is due the fact that webpage can play sounds from Java Script, HTML5 or any number of browser extensions like Flash Player, Shockwave Player etc. In order to mute sounds from your application you need to access Windows sound mixer.

Comment: Now if you want to have multi tab capabilities and have control over playing sounds for each tab separately then I'm you will have to implement similar way of managing multiple tabs as other browsers do where each tab is actually being processed in its own application instance.

Comment: Do you only want to suppress the sounds during loading? And then let them play once the pages have finished loading?

Comment: @SilverWarior No problem to mute all my application, i want NO sound to be played by my app

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I want to suprpess any sound that a web page could play, during or after loading.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It seems like the actual question of OP is a duplicate of the one you marked, but the question as posed (muting sound of chromium) certainly is not. Might be worth leaving it open to possibly get an answer to that question?

Comment: No because Google Chrome is probably not what is going to make the sound, a plugin like Flash is likely to make that sound.